# ngx-datatable - Material theme router animation

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm applying material theme to ngx-datatable and whenever I route to a component using ngx-datatable, there is some animation triggered on the table content.

You can see the demo here: [Demo](https://www.useloom.com/share/d04b73917eeb48fea01a814af7c0e420)

If I apply bootstrap theme, then no animation is played.

Is there any way to disable the animation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after refactoring components.

Comment: how did you fix this?